# Delayed frames while using WebGPU

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, rendering, webgpu

I have a WebApp that renders bicycle tracks on a map. Here is an example image:

[image: Image of the app working fine]

Here, the background Map is intentionally hidden for simplification.

Previously, everything was rendered using the CanvasRenderingContext2D API. I'm currently converting my code to WebGPU to improve performance. The green line is rendered using my custom code based on WebGPU. The red line is using the old CanvasRenderingContext2D api. As you can see, there are overlapping, so everything works fine.

The problem starts when I drag the map. The WebGPU rendering lags behind the old rendering, looking like this.

[image: Lines no longer overlapping]

If I stop dragging the map, everything looks fine again.

I initially thought that my code was buggy, but the problem is stranger than I thought. The problem occurs only ~ 80% of the time. Other times, everything works great. Switching tabs, opening dev tools, or changing the window size can make the problem appear or disappear. Therefore, I assume a performance problem or a browser bug.

The problem can be seen in Chrome and Edge Chromium. I don't think another browser engine has WebGPU support so far.

I have tried to build a small demo to reproduce the error but without success. Everything works fine in a smaller scenario. Therefore, I tend to assume a performance problem even more. I am using the context.setTransform function to move the content on the CanvasRenderingContext2D and a UniformBuffer on the WebGPU side. I have triple checked that both transformations are the same for every frame.

I have three ideas that could cause the problem:

1. The UniformBuffer is updated via queue.writeBuffer every frame before the draw command is called. Maybe sometimes the order of the commands is wrong.
2. The draw function is called via requestAnimationFrame. Maybe the next frame is drawn before the queue is executed completely. There is a function called queue.onSubmittedWorkDone to wait for the GPU to complete, but I can't see a way to use it in my render loop.
3. Maybe the problem is caused by the two overlapping canvas elements. I have the same setup in my working minimal demo, so I'm not convinced.

If you have any idea what might cause the problem, I would be very delighted.

Comment: If you're drawing to the 2d canvas and the webgpu canvas in different events then there is no guarantee they'll be in sync. For example, if they each have their own requestAnimationFrame callback, instead of a single callback that updates both canvases then they could be out of sync. Also you're using `await` that starts a new event. Otherwise, the three issues you listed should be unrelated.

Comment: Hello @gman thank you very much for your reply and your idea. I have just checked my code again. I'm using a single requestAnimationFrame callback for both canvas elements, so that's not the problem. I have also checked my code for async/await calls. There are none. So that's not the issue.

To fully verify the order, I have added some console.log calls to check the order. The result is as expected.

Start frame drawing 2392

Render WGPU 2392

Render CanvasRenderingContext2D 2392

End frame drawing 2392

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have just extended my log calls to show the order in more details. Here is the result:

- Start frame drawing 15857
- WGPU queue.writeBuffer 15857
- WGPU createCommandEncoder 15857
- WGPU GPUCommandEncoder.beginRenderPass 15857
- WGPU GPURenderPassEncoder.draw 15857
- WGPU GPUCommandEncoder.end 15857
- WGPU GPUCommandEncoder.finish 15857
- WGPU GPUQueue.submit 15857
- Render CanvasRenderingContext2D 15857
- End frame drawing 15857

Comment: you're going to have to post a repo and for the question not to be off topic it will need to be **in the question itself**.

Comment: @gman thank you again for your help. I was able to build a minimal version of my code where I can reproduce the same problem. During that, I found the origin of the problem.

The CanvasRendeingContext2d has the attribute [desyncronized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext?#desynchronized). I have added this attribute a long time ago to my old renderer. (I can't remember why). This attribute lead to the lagging behind of my webgpu canvas. (Maybe a browser bug)

I can simply remove the flag and everything works perfectly now.
Thank you!

Comment: For anybody interrested:
[Here](https://codepen.io/Kaladum/pen/yLZeqBr) is a demo with the problem/attribute intentionally added. (Can be provoked by changing the size of the DevConsole or by switching tabs).
And [here](https://imgur.com/a/X8MIyNN) is a picture of the bug in action.

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue. There's no bug though. desynchronized literally means not synchronized. That's what you asked for and what you got   see: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/desynchronized/